# setting textColor in TextView in layout/main.xml main layout file not referencing colors.xml file. (It wants a #RRGGBB instead of @color/text_color)

Tags: android

I'm trying to set some general colors for a program I'm writing. I created a colors.xml file and am trying to directly reference the colors from the layout.xml file. I believe I'm am doing this correctly however it's giving me the following error:

```
Color value '@colors/text_color' must start with #
```

Here is my res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#888888</color>
    <color name="text_color">#00FFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Here is my res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:textColor="@colors/text_color"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I looked at some references on the android developers site: [More Resource Types : Color](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) and found this code:

Example:XML file saved at res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves the color resource:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int color = res.getColor(R.color.opaque_red);
```

This layout XML applies the color to an attribute:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/translucent_red"
    android:text="Hello"/>
```

I think my two xml files follow this example pretty close - however the only difference is that I haven't used any application code to retrieve the color resource. I don't believe this is necessary (but it is a difference.) I thought I'd see if anyone else had similar problems or a solution? or is this a bug?

I did update all my android sdk (and Eclipse plugin) files last week so I believe them to be the latest.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After experimenting on that case:
`android:textColor="@colors/text_color"` is wrong since `@color` is not filename dependant. You can name your resource file foobar.xml, it doesn't matter but if you have defined some colors in it you can access them using `@color/some_color`.

**Update:**

> file location:
>   res/values/colors.xml
>   The filename is arbitrary. The  element's name will be used as the resource ID. ([Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color))

Answer (score 43):

A variation using just standard color code:

```
android:textColor="#ff0000"
```

Answer (score 20):

You have a typo in your xml; it should be:

```
android:textColor="@color/text_color"
```

that's "@color" without the 's'.

Answer (score 4):

You should write textcolor in xml as

```
android:textColor="@color/text_color"
```

or

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```