# how to change the color of a word within a string.xml file

Tags: android

I'm new to android and would like to know how to change the color of a specific word inside a strings.xml file
I'm trying to write a song and I needed the notes to have another color and the chorus to be bold

```html
<string name="homem_novo_seras_acordes">
        mi- \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t re\
        Um Homem Novo vai nascer\
        do \t\t\t\t sol \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t mi-\
        Neste dia onde tudo vai mudar\
        si-\
        Tens um mundo pra transformar\
</string>
```

Thanks

Comment: why not just change it on activity? attention this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286275/setting-textcolor-in-textview-in-layout-main-xml-main-layout-file-not-referencin/22411969

Comment: Please include the physical code as opposed to a screenshot of it on StackOverflow, this is much more useful for those who want to try helping and thereby for you as well. Surround your code block with \`\`\` on either side for it to render as a code sample in your post.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you can achieve multicolor text using a **Spannable** string.

To know more how to do it, check this developer blog
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568